# Which Harry Potter set is this table from?

Tags: set-identification, harry-potter

[image: table]

I have been gifted a lot of 10 + years old Lego. I don't have any instructions books. Any idea what sets could these be so I could try to find them online please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can identify the following parts:

- 2 of "Cheese slope" in reddish brown
- 2 of 1x1 round plate in trans-**neon**-orange
- 2 of 2x8 plate in dark tan

[A search based on that criteria](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=54200&itemSeq1=4&colorID1=88&itemNo2=4073&itemSeq2=2&colorID2=18&itemNo3=3034&itemSeq3=2&colorID3=69&in=S) yields only one result: [set 4182 "The Cannibal Escape"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4182-1) from the Pirates of the Caribbean franchise.

One of the sub-assemblies in the set resembles the one in your photograph very closely:

[image: set 4182, highlighting sub-assembly]

Alas, you don't have a Harry Potter table. You have a cannibal bonfire.

Comment: Ah, right, trans-*neon*-orange... /facepalm. Nice find!

Comment: Thank you @IvanSanchez definitely the Cannibal Escape as I have found other elements in my Lego box!. You are such a great help!

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: this answer is based on a false premise and is therefore invalid. See IvanSanchez's answer instead.

---

The photo clearly shows 2 of *Reddish Brown Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with 1 Stud with Groove (Jumper)* and *Trans-Orange Plate, Round 1 x 1*, and 4 each of *Reddish Brown Plate 1 x 4* and *Reddish Brown Slope 30 1 x 1 x 2/3*. There were only two sets in which all of these have appeared: [79003: An Unexpected Gathering](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=79003-1) and [10236: Ewok Village - UCS](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10236-1), but neither of these have a 2x8 plate in any colours besides black, green or reddish brown - none of which corresponds to the ones your photo depicts.

So this sub-assembly must not have come from an official set, or at least some parts have been added to it.

---

Edit based on Henrik's comment:

Updating the search to include piece 15573 (*Modified 1 x 2 with 1 Stud with Groove and Bottom Stud Holder (Jumper)*) results in matches for [71040 Disney Castle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=71040-1) (contains only dark bluish gray and white 2x8 plates), [70677 Land Bounty](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70677-1) (just reddish brown 2x8), [40346 Legoland Park](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=40346-1) (green and white), [910003 Mountain Windmill](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=910003-1) (reddish brown) and [75220 Sandcrawler](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75220-1) (which has the *Tile, Modified 1 x 1 with Open O Clip* only in dark bluish gray instead of black).

Switching out the jumper plate with groove (3794b) to the one without (3794a) yields no additional candidates.

Comment: I don't find it clear from the image that there is a groove on those jumpers, if there isn't those parts are old though, but the 2x8 plates also look old gray to me, which would also suggest some age - and neither of those observations conflict with the conclusion that this is not from an official set.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity The old light gray 2x8 has never appeared alongside reddish brown 1x4s and reddish brown cheese slopes: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=3034&itemSeq1=2&colorID1=9&itemNo2=3710&itemSeq2=4&colorID2=88&itemNo3=54200&itemSeq3=4&colorID3=88&in=S